# "Cannot initialize a ClientFunction because find is string, and not a function" error when attempting to locate element

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am receiving this `Cannot initialize a ClientFunction because find is string, and not a function.` error and I am unsure on how to fix it.

What I am trying to do is depending the type provided as the parameter, it will attempt to find the correct page element.

The error points to here:

```
  let location: Selector = this.deviceName
         221 |      .withText(nameText)
         222 |      .parent('.device')
       > 223 |      .find(balanceLocator);
```

This is my function:

```
 let initialBalance = await cashPage.getBalance(
    'safe',
    'Box 232'
  );

...

class cashPage extends BasePage {
deviceName: Selector;
cashierBalance: Selector;
safeBalance: Selector;
}

constructor() {
    super();
    this.cashierBalance = Selector('.balance-cashier');
    this.safeBalance = Selector('.balance-safe');
    this.deviceName = Selector('.device-name');
}

 async getBalance(type: string, name: string) {
    let balanceLocator: any, nameText: string;
    switch (type) {
      case 'cashier': {
        balanceLocator = this.cashierBalance;
        break;
      }
      case 'safe': {
        balanceLocator = this.safeBalance;
        break;
      }
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unrecognised type provided`);
    }

    type == 'cashier' ? (nameText = name.toLowerCase()) : (nameText = name);

    let location: Selector = this.deviceName
      .withText(nameText)
      .parent('.device')
      .find(balanceLocator);

    let balanceAmount = (await location.textContent);

    return Number(balanceAmount).toFixed(2);
  }
```

What I have found out is that if I replace the edit the switch statement so that the `deviceBalanceLocator` s equal to the actual string, then it works:

```
async getBalance(type: string, name: string) {
    let balanceLocator: any, nameText: string;
    switch (type) {
      case 'cashier': {
        balanceLocator = '.balance-cashier';
        break;
      }
      case 'safe': {
        balanceLocator = '.balance-safe';
        break;
      }
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unrecognised type provided`);
    }
```

But I was hoping to use the variable locator and not typing the actual string again, if that's possible?